# Get all method execution times on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, execution-time

Is there a way to get execution time for every method on ASP.NET server using c#, without using something like StopWatch class for every method or something... ?

Comment: Have a look at the performance counters available. lots of them nowadays (including Asp.Net, WCF , etc. etc.) Maybe its what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option if you want to record this information while it is running in production without the use of Visual Studio would be to use an [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) solution like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/).

You could create a custom aspect which uses a Stopwatch to time method execution and log the results. Once the aspect is written it is trivially simple to apply it to every method in your project. There is an article on how to do this [here](http://www.rajeeshcv.com/post/details/30/logging-execution-time-using-aop).

Answer (score 2):

Use a profiler, like [Visual Studio's built-in performance analyzer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx)